# What is the reason to get exit status value -1 in JSch

Tags: java, ssh, jsch

I am trying to run a command on a remote Linux box from Java using JSch (SSH) API. The value of `exitStatus` is `-1` i.e.

```
int exitStatus = channelExec.getExitStatus()
```

What is the possible reason to get a negative value?

Comment: The command didn't succeed!

Comment: When I run the same command from console (putty) it works :/

Comment: Try reading error message from channelExec.getErrStream()

Comment: Tried @Manu it shows nothing :(

Comment: http://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/simple.javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/Channel.html#getExitStatus%28%29

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note [the documentation](http://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/simple.javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/Channel.html#getExitStatus%28%29) on getExitStatus().

The exit status will be -1 until the channel is closed.

Answer (score 3):

[API Description](http://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/simple.javadoc/)

Here is my code. It works fine.

```
public static Result sendCommand(String ip, Integer port, String userName, String password, String cmd) {
    Session session = null;
    ChannelExec channel = null;
    Result result = null;
    try {
        JSch jsch = new JSch();
        JSch.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");

        session = jsch.getSession(userName, ip, port);
        session.setPassword(password);
        session.connect();   

        channel = (ChannelExec)session.openChannel("exec");
        InputStream in = channel.getInputStream();
        channel.setErrStream(System.err);
        channel.setCommand(cmd);
        channel.connect();

        StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            message.append(line).append("\n");
        }
        channel.disconnect();
        while (!channel.isClosed()) {

        }
        result = new Result(channel.getExitStatus(),message.toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (session != null) {
            try {
                session.disconnect();
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: channel.setErrStream(System.err); Really helped me out to find why my input stream is always 0...

Answer (score 2):

'-1' means that the exit status code has not been received yet from the remote sshd.

Comment: It indeed returned -1 when I gave it no chance to wait for the output to be transferred. If you wait for the result, it is likely to change

Answer (score 0):

`channelName.getExitStatus()`

it will retrieve the exit status of the remote command corresponding to your channel. If the command is **not yet terminated** (or this channel type has no command), it will return the status as **-1**.

For more got to [jsch documentation](http://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/simple.javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/Channel.html#getExitStatus%28%29).